# How to print iterations with solver run time?

Tags: python

I am struggling to print the time in output. I want to run this program and take note of each iteration time. I think I am missing the main body. I'm new to programming.

import itertools
    import pandas as pd
    import time

```
file_name = 'cases/case1_1md_2mec_4jobs.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)

df_mec = xl.parse('MECs')
df_job = xl.parse('Jobs')

#print df_mec
#print df_job


individual_options = [] #a list that will store individual options for each job
for job in df_job['ID']:
    options = []
    options.append([job,0]) #job is processed locally
    for mec in df_mec['MEC ID']:
        options.append([job,mec])
    individual_options.append(options)

#the following command will generate all the combinations
total_options = (list(itertools.product(*individual_options)))

#print total_options

#write the options to a csv file
with open('all_sceduling_options.csv','w') as file:
    for option in total_options:
        for job,mec2 in option:
            file.write(str(job)+'-'+str(mec2)+',')
        file.write('\n')




f = open('run_time_of_all_the_options.csv', 'w')
for i in range(0,1):
    start = time.time()
    print 'iteration: ', i

    end = time.time()

    print "Time is taken by the Solver", end-start

f.write(str(i)+','+str(end-start)+'\n')

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to indent the printout so that it applies to all passes through your loop and not just the last one:

```
for i in range(0,1):
    start = time.time()
    print 'iteration: ', i

    end = time.time()

    print "Time is taken by the Solver", end-start

    f.write("Iteration: "+str(i)+','+str(end-start)+'\n') # << Extra tab at start of line here makes this happen for each pass through your for loop
```

Comment: I want to print iterations, for example, iteration 0: 0.04 iteration1: 0.03 and so on in the loop.

Comment: So just add the string "Iteration: " to the start of your `f.write` function.  You can format the strings you write however you like